# Algorithm and pseudocode from a flowchart

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, flowchart

[image]

I'm new to programming, and I became stuck here where I have to write an algorithm and pseudo code for this flowchart, but I'm confused on how to do the loop delay 2 seconds, or the add 2 seconds until it hits 10.

Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html

Comment: The delay could be something like `c = clock() + 2 seconds ; while (clock() < c);`

Comment: `COUNTER = 0` and then `WAIT 2 SECONDS`. It's not clear what form the pseudo-code is supposed to take, but it's probably ok to write whatever commands you like as long as the result is a series of lines of text resembling the form of a conventional programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I think that psuedocode can sometimes be harder than writing real code for people who are just starting. The psuedocode for those instructions can be pretty-well exactly as in the flowchard:

How to do the *loop delay 2 seconds*:

```
while (door_sensor_read is no)
    sleep for 2 seconds
```

and the *add 2 seconds until it hits 10*:

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo code would be:

```
while (counter < 10)
{
    sensor read = read the door;
    while (sensor read == closed)
    {
        counter = 0;
        sleep 2000ms;
    }

    counter += 2;
    sleep 2000ms;
}

sound alarm;
```